# Please give the solution regarding the error

Tags: customer-attribute

Please Help me i found this error.

> Uncaught Error: [object Object]
>       at Object. (/looper/en/pub/static/frontend/Szdev/loopper/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js:92)
>       at fire (/looper/en/pub/static/frontend/Szdev/loopper/en_US/jquery.js:3232)
>       at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (/looper/en/pub/static/frontend/Szdev/loopper/en_US/jquery.js:3362)
>       at done (/looper/en/pub/static/frontend/Szdev/loopper/en_US/jquery.js:9842)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.callback (/looper/en/pub/static/frontend/Szdev/loopper/en_US/jquery.js:10311)

Comment: Please provide more detail?